# Will using nested ViewStacks cause my performance to decrease?

Tags: performance, apache-flex

Will I take a big hit in performance using nested ViewStacks? Should I strive to handle all navigation in one ViewStack and push children manually or will the affected performance be negligible?

eg.

```
<viewstack>
    <tabnavigator />
    <tabnavigator />
    <tabnavigator />
</viewstack>
```

Comment: Test it and see!  Is the app having performance problems?

Comment: The application is still in the design stages. It is going to be a very large app so I want to make sure I get everything straight before I touch the code.

Comment: What you do inside your views will be much more important to performance than how you orchestrate your view stack.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it should matter, it could be a good thing depending on the creationPolicy.

Check out the Adobe Docs: `http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/layoutperformance_05.html`

You can set the creationPolicy to "auto" which will only create the components inside a view when the view is activated.  So if you have a bunch of nested components it will still only created the views when they are activated...meaning I don't think nesting them will have any affect on performance.

There is a slight performance hit from nesting MXML elements, but on the desktop, this is very minor.  You only have to really worry about that if you're doing a mobile air app, then you want to make it very flat and probably don't want to use MXML at all.  And even in a mobile app, I would only worry about it if you were doing a list.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Flex 4 or higher, you should probably use States.